# I got my car back!

Tags: grammar, translation, conjugations

Just for a silly post I want to make, I want to say, "Ya!  I got my car back!"  My attempt at this is 「やった！僕の車復帰した！」 As in, I was without my car for a few days while it was being repaired, and now I have it again.

Is this correct?  I looked up "returned" and 復帰 sounded like it expressed what I wanted.  It was defined as a suru verb, so is した correct conjugation for past tense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are saying this jokingly, you would not use a big Sino-loanword like 「復帰{ふっき}」 at all.  Trust me, you would sound more than weird if you used it.

Native speakers would say:

> 「やっ**と**車{くるま}が戻{もど}ってきた！」

We would not use the pronoun "my" here because everyone would know whose car you are talking about.

Lastly, we do not use 「やっ**た**」 nearly as often as Japanese-learners have been using it recently.

Comment: Is 「やっと」more like "yay!" here or (as my dictionary says) "finally!"  I'm curious because in English using "yay" just implies excitement while "finally" used instead adds a bit of "I'm excited but it took longer than I would have liked."

Comment: @Andy やっと is certainly more like "Finally!" in English, but is certainly more proper to use in Japanese for situations such as these. やった might be an exclamation such as "yay!" in English but Japanese people in general don't really exclaim this way that often? Just how pervasive and commonplace "Yay" in English is, is certainly the reason why more Japanese-learners lean toward expressing excitement with やった where in Japanese it might be implied or expressed merely with the tone of one's voice

Comment: @psosuna I understand your point about 「やった」, and I'm fine with 「やっと」, I'm just curious if it adds any negativity like using "finally" might in (written) English.  These subtle things can be tricky :-)

Comment: @Andy I totally agree with l'électeur about 復帰, but やっと and やった are so different and I don't understand why he changed it this way. If he doesn't like やった, he should have suggested よっしゃ, or anything he usually uses. Anyway, I believe やった is not bad at all, at least as a blog post, tweet, etc.

Comment: Thanks @naruto, good to have another perspective.  I just took l'electeur's comment as its just not something a native speaker would say, which I am interested in knowing as well.

Comment: @Andy: I think there are two kinds of ways to express a joy. They are  a dynamic joy and a static joy. "やった！" is a dynamic joy suitable to express one's excitement positively, while "やっと" is not simply "finally" but the expression of "安堵感{あんどかん} *sense of relief* or *feeling of relief*" of getting back one's car repaired without problems.